# getting python object derived properties

Tags: python

So I wanted to get all the properties from an object and I found this code online:

```
class A(object):

    @property
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "type_A"

    def properties(self):
        result={}
        for cls in self.__class__.__mro__:
            for varname, value in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
                if isinstance(value, property):
                    result[varname] = value.fget(self)
        return result
```

But when I started to define classes derived from class A like this:

```
class B(A):

    @property
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "type_B"
```

I ran into the following problem:

```
a = A()
b = B()

a.typeInfo #returns: type_A
b.typeInfo #returns: type_B

a.properties #returns: {'typeInfo': 'type_A'}
b.properties #returns: {'typeInfo': 'type_A'}
```

So I realized I did not fully understand what the code I found was doing and started to dig a bit more. I found this other code:

```
def properties2(self):
    result={}
    for cls in self.__class__.__mro__:
        for varname, value in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, property):
                result[varname] = getattr(self, varname)
    return result
```

which would return:

```
a.properties2 #returns: {'typeInfo': 'type_A'}
b.properties2 #returns: {'typeInfo': 'type_B'}
```

Ok so now I admit I really don't understand the difference
Why the first solution is returning the parent's value instead of its own value?

Here is the full code for convenience:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "default name"

    @property
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "type_A"

    def properties(self):
        result={}
        for cls in self.__class__.__mro__:
            for varname, value in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
                if isinstance(value, property):
                    result[varname] = value.fget(self)
        return result

    def properties2(self):
        result={}
        for cls in self.__class__.__mro__:
            for varname, value in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
                if isinstance(value, property):
                    result[varname] = getattr(self, varname)
        return result

class B(A):

    @property
    def typeInfo(self):
        return "type_B"


a = A()
b = B()

print "a.typeInfo:\t", a.typeInfo
print "b.typeInfo:\t", b.typeInfo
print ""
print "With properties:"
print "a.properties:\t", a.properties()
print "b.properties:\t", b.properties()
print ""
print "With properties2:"
print "a.properties2:\t", a.properties2()
print "b.properties2:\t", b.properties2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all note that you are assigning same dictionary item twice. `varname` is the same for `B` and for `A`. So when you run `b.properties()` property from `A` shadows property from `B`.

For the second example you never try to access `A.typeInfo()` when calling `b.properties2()`. Function ends calling `getattr(b, 'typeInfo')` twice.

You can fix it, for example, by prefixing `varname` with class name. If you don't won't to store overridden properties, you can revert `__mro__` list.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am assigning the same item twice, therefore both solutions are wrong, the second only appearing to be correct because I call getattr(0 on the same object.

Comment: Ok so how would you get a list of all the properties (of type property ) of an object? What is the correct way for doing that? (anything I found so far was variation on these lines of code)

Comment: Depends on what do you want. If you want to hide overridden properties just use your `properties()` and `reversed(self.__class__.__mro__)` in a `for` loop. If you want to have them, prefix names in a dict with class name: `result["%s.%s" % (cls.__name__, varname)] = value.fget(self)`

Comment: yep I want only the object's properties so reversing does the job. Thanks!